# Is a user-defined class in Python an object itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I have a question to ask you people regarding the behaviour of a class in Python and the scope of a class in Python.
Is class itself in Python an object?. I have read some theory about user-defined classes in Python. The theory says that a class in Python itself a class object and that is the reason that we get an id for a user-defined class. If we assume that a class in Python is an object then does a class occupy memory considering that a class is a blueprint?

```
class Curiousity:
  
   variable="still Curious"
 
print (id(Curiousity))
```

> 18234408

Comment: Yes, a class is an object. Everything is an object.

Comment: a class is an **instance** of `type` (you can generally read "instance" as "object")

Answer (score 1):

> [...] then does a class occupy memory considering that a class is a blueprint?

Why not test it yourself, using `sys.getsizeof` to get the memory size of an object:

```py
import sys


class Curiousity:
    variable = "still Curious"


print(sys.getsizeof(Curiousity))
```

Out:

```
1072
```

Memory footprint of a class can be reduced or managed using a [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785) attribute:

```py
import sys


class Curiousity:
    __slots__ = ()
    variable = "still Curious"


print(sys.getsizeof(Curiousity))  # now shows as: 904
```